# What substance did artists use to outline the shadow boundaries on anime cels?

Tags: anime-production

[image: Reference Photo]

The referenced photo clearly shows a special type of colored ink used to outline the shadow boundaries on Asuka. My guess, from observing a cel that I own, is that they outlined the shadows with a thinned out paint, gouache, or maybe a thicker type of colored ink. I would really appreciate it if anyone knows what is used because I'm looking to buy some for myself. Much thanks.